# How to free a structure of linked structures

Tags: c, linked-list, structure

I have this structure

```
struct room {
    char* name;               
    char* description;         
    struct room *north;       
    struct room *south;       
    struct room *east;       
    struct room *west;          
    struct container* items;   
};
```

So I should write a function 
`struct room* destroy_room(struct room* room);`
that frees all the memory used for room creation and return NULL as new room reference.
So i thought that simply doing

```
free(room);
return NULL;
```

would resolve the problem, but it didn't.

Comment: Basically each and every chunk of memory you've obtained via `malloc` and friends must be freed via a call to `free`. Nothing is freed automatically.

Comment: How where the memory for the rooms allocated? Was it allocated as a single connected memory space like `malloc(sizeof(struct room) * N)` or was the memory for each room allocated speratly?

Comment: Also what about the strings in `name` and `description`.

Comment: it was allocated separately, there is another function for create_room, where you put name and description as parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go with a solution using two seperate functions. The first is `destroy_room` it will free one single room and remove the references to itself from its neighbors:

```c
struct room* destroy_room(struct room* room) {
    if (!room) return;
    if (room->name) free(room->name);
    if (room->description) free(room->description);
    if (room->items) free_items(room->items);

    // remove the references to this room from its neighbors
    if (room->north) room->north->south = NULL;
    if (room->south) room->south->north = NULL;
    if (room->east) room->east->west = NULL;
    if (room->west) room->west->east = NULL;

    free(room);

    return NULL;
}
```

This function can then be used to write a recursive function ro free all rooms that are reachable from the given room. The function saves the references to the neighbors, then frees the given room and then recursivly frees the neighbors:

```c
struct room* destroy_rooms_rec(struct room* room)
{
    if (!room) return;

    // save references to neighbors
    struct room* north = room->north;
    struct room* south = room->south;
    struct room* east = room->east;
    struct room* west = room->west;

    // free this room
    destroy_room(room);

    // free all neighbors
    destroy_rooms_rec(north);
    destroy_rooms_rec(south);
    destroy_rooms_rec(east);
    destroy_rooms_rec(west);

    return NULL;
}
```

Note: I assumed that a function like `free_items(struct container* items)` exists that can free whatever `items` is.

**EDIT:** I noticed that this code has a implicit assumtions. 
It assumes that the graph build by the rooms has a tree structure. If the graph is a fully conected grid or has any cycles this code won't work and leeds to memory problems like double free and invalid access.

But I'm working on a solution for any graph

Comment: One minor detail: `free()` can be safely called with a `NULL` pointer as its argument, so technically the `NULL` checks for name and description (and possibly items) aren't necessary and could be removed.

Answer (score 2):

As Jabberwocky says, "nothing is freed automatically", so your function could look like:

```
void destroy_room(struct room* room)
{
    if (!room) return;
    if (room->name) free(room->name);
    if (room->description) free(room->description);
    if (room!=room->north) destroy_room(room->north);
    if (room!=room->south) destroy_room(room->south);
    if (room!=room->east) destroy_room(room->east);
    if (room!=room->west) destroy_room(room->west);
    free_items(room->items);
    free(room);
}
```

Comment: using this code, valgrind gave me 2 Invalid free() errors, at lines where you free name and description.

Comment: Ok I didn't assign allocated text in create_room function, but simply write text as parameters. This works.

Comment: If `room->north->south == room` (so double linked rooms) then this will end in a stackoverflow. And I would assume that the rooms are doubly linked.

Comment: Note that this will not just free one room, but all of them. If you only want to free a single room, then you need to remove the recursive calls to `destroy_room`.

Comment: This will also lose the memory pointed to by `items` (if it is not managed somewhere else)